# How to prove this probability inequality?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am reading Gregory F. Lawler's *Random Walk and the Heat Equation*. In page 45, there is

Exercise 1.8. Suppose $X_1, X_2,\ldots$ are independent random variables each of whose distribution is symmetric about $0$. Show that for every $a>0$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\{\text{max}_{1\leq j\leq n}X_1+\ldots+X_j\geq a\}\leq 2\mathbb{P}\{X_1+\ldots+X_n\geq a\}.
$$

How to prove this inequality?

There is a hint saying that let $K$ be the smallest $j$ with $X_1+\ldots+X_j\geq a$ and consider
$$
\mathbb{P}\{X_1+\ldots+X_n\geq a|K=j\}.
$$
But I don't know how to use this hint either.

Comment: This is known as the "*Reflection Principle*", you should be able to find a proof online...

Comment: @FeiCao I see. Actually the key part is to notice that $\mathbb{P}\{X_1+\ldots+X_n\geq a|K=j\}\geq 1/2$ for each $j$.